# How to change a span to look like a pre with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to to change a `<span>` tag (or `<div>`) to preformat its contents like a `<pre>` tag would using only CSS?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Look at the [W3C CSS2.1 Default Style Sheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) or the [CSS2.2 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html). Copy all the settings for PRE and put them into your own class.

```css
pre {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to do it this way in order to understand where these defaults come from.

Comment: When I try this, the line breaks are not preserved.

Comment: The <pre> tag will display horizontal scrollbars when the text is too wide, but this css will not.  Anyone know how to show them?

Comment: @shindigo Have you tried using `overflow: scroll`? Or if you only want horizontal scrolling `overflow-x: scroll`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: @shindigo ```overflow: auto;``` may be better otherwise you may end up with two sets of scrollbars when you don't need them.

Answer (score 65):

See [the white-space CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space).

```
.like-pre { white-space: pre; }
```

Comment: alternatively, you may find `white-space: pre-wrap` useful. It behaves like `pre`, but wraps long lines.

Answer (score 28):

This makes a SPAN look like a PRE:

```
span {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: block;
}
```

Remember to change the css selector as appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically, the property you're looking at is:

```
white-space: pre
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop

Answer (score 5):

while the accepted answer is indeed correct, if you want the text to wrap you should use:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
span {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this style

```
.pre {

white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
white-space: -pre-wrap;
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
line-height: 1.5;   
word-break: break-all;
white-space: pre;
white-space: pre\9; /* IE7+ */
display: block;
}
```

Used the same here - [http://www.makemyshop.in/](http://www.makemyshop.in/Snapdeal)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the <pre> tag, instead of the span tag? Both are inline, so both should behave in the way you would like. If you have a problem overriding the entire definition of <pre>, just give it a class/id.

Comment: Sometimes you already have a span on a page and can't change it, like if it's part of an existing CMS system.

Comment: B/c the framework is refusing to put the contents under my <pre> the way I'm asking it to.  I could work around it, but that's a lot harder than just setting a few CSS props.