# Can I have a <pre> Tag inside a <p> tag in Tumblr?

Tags: html, templates, tumblr

today I played around a little bit with Tumblr.
I tried to add a preformatted text into a description paragraph block like so:

```
{block:Description}
    <p id="description">{Description}</p>
{/block:Description}
```

However, the `<pre>` element gets rendered just after the `<p>` element and not within it which was my intention.

Am I doing something wrong here or is it a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot nest block-level elements, such as [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4), inside [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P) in HTML, so Tumblr is behaving correctly. You should close your paragraph before inserting the pre-formatted text.

If you want inline code-style text, try the [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) tag. You can then supplement it with CSS if needed.

```
<p>I like to use the <code>code</code> tag in my HTML files.</p>
```

```
code
{
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I tried replacing <p> by <div> which is a block element, too and it worked! And isn't nesting <div>s a common practice? I am baffled again...

Comment: Happy to help. `<div>` is a grouping element and can be nested; it's particularly useful with CSS, much like `<span>`.

Comment: So there are block level elements which cannot be nested unless it is a grouping block level element? Obviously I underestimated html complexity :). Could you provide a link where I can learn more about this concept?

Comment: `<div>` and `<span>` are **not** *block-level* elements, they are *grouping* elements. In my answer I linked to [The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) (for HTML 4.01), that should help you.

Answer (score 2):

Also, I just realized where I was having a similar issue pasting code into tumblr inside `<pre>` and `<code>` tags is that just because you wrap your code in those tags doesn't prevent you from having to escape the carets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of the carets.

Answer (score 2):

And the HTML5 terminology is:

- `p`'s "Content model" is "Phrasing content": "https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element
- `pre`'s "Categories" are: "Flow content" and "Palpable content": https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element

Since `pre`'s categories don't include "Phrasing content", `pre` cannot be put inside `p`.

Maybe it is possible to simulate `pre` with CSS styles though: [How to change a span to look like a pre with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219219/how-to-change-a-span-to-look-like-a-pre-with-css/219230#219230) but I'm not sure it is allowed in `p`.

See also: [List of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside P element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element)