# Nesting <p> won't work while nesting <div> will?

Tags: html, nested, paragraph

I usually won't nest `<p>` like this:

```
<p>The following:
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
</p>
```

and I will nest like that using `<div>` instead.  But today I used `<p>` but it seems that both Emacs and Google Chrome both would consider the outer `<p>` closed as soon as it see a new `<p>` is started.  (the `DOCTYPE` is HTML 4.01 Strict).

I thought `<p>` is no more than a `<div>` but just with some pre-defined margin and padding, but is it true that `<p>` cannot be nested?  If so, what rule says that it cannot?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Because a paragraph is a paragraph .. and that's how HTML is defined (and HTML is *not* XML).

Any `<p>` (or *other* block-level element) will *implicitly close* any open `<p>`.

Per [9.3.1 Paragraphs: the P element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) of the HTML 4.01 specification:

> The P element represents a paragraph. It *cannot* contain block-level elements (including P itself).

---

Note that this is *how the HTML is parsed* and that even a `<div>` would have implicitly closed the paragraph!

However, a `<span>` with `display:block;` would *not* have closed the `<p>` as a `<span>` is *not* a block-level element.

That is, the CSS is *irrelevant* at this stage of the HTML processing and the CSS is *irrelevant* to the DOM/parser when determining if an element is a block-level element or not. Consider the case when CSS is applied dynamically or through a not-yet-loaded-stylesheet: the applied CSS does not alter the DOM.

---

While the HTML5 (working-draft) specification does not include the language above in the HTML4 specification, it does go on to define a paragraph as a *container* for [phasing content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#phrasing-content) and further has a [section on paragraphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#paragraphs).

The accepted answer to [List of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside P element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element) says that `<p>` elements cannot nest in HTML5. The key phrase from the documentation is: "Runs of phrasing content [which does not include `<p>` elements] form paragraphs". Furthermore, HTML5, trying to be backwards-compatible in many aspects, has a rationale on ["Restrictions on content models and on attribute values"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values):

> *Certain elements are parsed in somewhat eccentric ways (typically for historical reasons)*, and their content model restrictions are intended to avoid exposing the author to these issues.

This behavior is referenced from [a HTML5 WG wiki entry on flow content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/FlowContentInObject#For_block_content_as_children_of_object_as_children_of__p):

> HTML5's restrictions on nesting of p elements and on what p elements may contain, are due to, quote: “peculiarities of the parser” that *causes p to be auto-closed* ..

Answer (score 14):

From the [HTML 4.01 specification section 9.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Comment: so `<p>` is like a `<div>` but a special case one?

Comment: No, it (`p`) is **not** a `div`.

Comment: Actually, I think `<div>` is intended to be a much more general element for use with CSS. `<p>` is a legacy from the old days when people formatted HTML by hand.

Comment: `<p>` is *not legacy* it defines *semantic intent* -- not surprisingly, a paragraph. If `<p>` is defined as *legacy* then we should also get rid of `<hX>` elements .. after all, they could be represented with `<div>` ..

Comment: @pst `<p>` is a block element, like `<div>`, and has margin, padding, border... and follow the Standard Compliant box model... so isn't it quite like `<div>` in these aspects?

Comment: @pst so you mean you don't consider CSS at all, but just looking at it purely in a semantic way, that `<div>` is a generic container, while `<p>` very specifically says a paragraph?

Comment: I am saying that the *parsing of the HTML* is not related to CSS. (I misspoke, being a block-element is *exactly* why the `<p>` cannot be nested, as it *cannot* contain block-elements. But this happens *during parsing*; not layout. For instance, a `<span>` with `display:block` would *not* have closed the paragraph element.)

Comment: @pst but I thought `<div>` is also a block element, and this block element can be nested

Comment: Please see the specification. Again. **It (P) cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).**

Comment: @pst ok, being block element is not the only reason that `<p>` cannot be nested.  The reason is that it is a block element, together with the fact that `<p>` cannot contain another block element.  These two combined as the reason, not just because it is a block element

Comment: The one and only reason why `<p>` cannot be nested is *because that is how it is defined*. Nothing more, nothing less. If that little clause was *not* in the specification, the it *could* be nested .. but then that would *not* be the HTML 4.01 specification

Comment: @pst actually, I do feel that, why can't a paragraph contain any block element?  In common usage, we may have a paragraph, and this paragraph can quote a short line and then continue on, so this quote is more logically part of this paragraph as a unit, rather than a separate entity outside of this paragraph. But of course if that's the way it is, then people have to design according to this rule