# Parent <span> style not applied to child <p>

Tags: html, css

If I have

```
<span style='display:none'>
    <p>this is some stuff</p>
    <p>more stuff</p>
</span>
```

my nested `<p>` tags are hidden as I would have expected.   The moment I add a `<p>` as a parent

```
<p>Some stuff
    <span style='display:none'>
        <p>this is some stuff</p>
        <p>more stuff</p>
    </span>  
</p>
```

The nested `<p>` tags are no longer hidden.   While I can change the `<p>` to a `<div>` to get it to work, I don't understand ***why*** the former fails.

The above is a boiled down version of my actual markup.  Changing to a `<div>` means reworking a lot so I'd like to find a way to use the `<p>` (or at least understand the rationale).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't put a <p> inside another <p> http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#paragraph

Comment: A `span` element can't contain a `p` element. You're seeing browsers trying to "correct" your code (closing the span before the p begins for instance)

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will and some other similar questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what could try to interpret a browser:

```
<span style='display:none'>
    </span><p>this is some stuff</p>
    <p>more stuff</p>
</span><!-- invalid, no opening tag -->
```

and

```
<p>Some stuff
    <span style='display:none'>
        </span></p><p>this is some stuff</p>
        <p>more stuff</p>
    </span><!-- invalid, no opening tag -->
</p><!-- invalid, no opening tag -->
```

In HTML5, many elements don't need to be closed (if the browser can programmatically determine where it should close) so in first example, that's what is happening: closing the span before the p begins.
In the second example, as stated by others, a p can't contain another paragraph so browser will close the first one before the second one begins.

- use an HTML validator. Any error may have consequences in browsers, and you don't know which ones/how for sure. Time is better spent validating pages than trying to correct in your code something that's due to your code ;)
- Use 2 sibling paragraphs and/or a parent `div`

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest `<p>` tags. And in HTML5 a `<span>` can't contain a `<p>`. Running your code through a validator would've told you this.

Answer (score 0):

First, `p` elements can't be nested. Any opening `<p>` tag after another opening `<p>` is threated by the browser as `</p><p>`, because end tag for `p` [is optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags). Also, `span` element can't contain `p` elements, so browser has to [correct this markup as broken](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser). Together these rules result in DOM tree where 2nd and following `p` elements are not children of `span` any more.

You should always respect [content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models) of the elements to avoid this problem.