# Angular ng-repeat in an ng-if wrapped in another ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Not sure exactly what's going on, but it looks like my expressions are not getting evaluated or expanded.

```
        <div ng-repeat-start="q in questions">
            <h3>{{q.text}}</h3>

                <p ng-if="q.type == 'checkbox'">
                    <p ng-repeat-start="a in q.answers">1 {{q.type}}
                        <input type={{q.type}}>{{a.text}}</input><br/>
                    </p>
                    <p ng-repeat-end></p>
                </p>

                <p ng-if="q.type == 'radio'">
                    <p ng-repeat-start="a in q.answers">2 {{q.type}}
                        <input type={{q.type}}>{{a.text}}</input><br/>
                    </p>
                    <p ng-repeat-end></p>
                </p>
        </div>
        <p ng-repeat-end></p>
```

The output shows the code is executing every if, as if they were both true.  This produces duplicate checkoboxes/radio buttons.

```
    1 checkbox  Voice calling.
    1 checkbox  Text messaging.
    1 checkbox  Data access 
    2 checkbox  Voice calling.
    2 checkbox  Text messaging.
    2 checkbox  Data access
```

It should look like this:

```
    1 checkbox  Voice calling.
    1 checkbox  Text messaging.
    1 checkbox  Data access
    2 radio  new question 1.
    2 radio  new question 2.
    2 radio  new question 3.
```

Comment: can you share an example of 'q' object

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `nested p` tag [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will)

```
<p>this
  <p>will not work</p>
</p>
```

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

In that case `ng-if` directive will not evaluate properly. So if you use `div` or `span` instead of `p` then it should works

```
    <div ng-repeat-start="q in questions">
        <h3>{{q.text}}</h3>

            <span ng-if="q.type == 'checkbox'">
                <p ng-repeat-start="a in q.answers">1 {{q.type}}
                    <input type={{q.type}}>{{a.text}}<br/>
                </p>
                <p ng-repeat-end></p>
            </span>

            <span ng-if="q.type == 'radio'">
                <p ng-repeat-start="a in q.answers">2 {{q.type}}
                    <input type={{q.type}}>{{a.text}}<br/>
                </p>
                <p ng-repeat-end></p>
            </span>

    </div>
    <p ng-repeat-end></p>
```

see the **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9uia7lD5dp5GfHHp6FXz?p=preview)**

Comment: +1 Nice job, I should've spotted that one. Deleted my answer.

Comment: It worked!  How about that.  I tried `<!-- ngIf: q.type == 'checkbox' -->` which did not work.  Thanks for the info.