# ng-if doesn't remove sub elements?

Tags: angularjs

According to the [docs](http://If%20the%20expression%20is%20falsy%20then%20the%20element%20is%20removed%20from%20the%20DOM%20tree.%20If%20it%20is%20truthy%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20compiled%20element%20is%20added%20to%20the%20DOM%20tree.) :

> If the expression is `falsy` then the element is removed from the DOM
>   tree. If it is truthy a copy of the compiled element is added to the
>   DOM tree.

*(I'm using ver 1.4.8)*

But  looking at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yAyQbqJ5y806sfkKlZx6?p=preview) :

I have this markup :

```
 <p ng-if="null">
        <p ng-include="'1.html'">***</p>
 </p>
```

Where `1.html` is :

```
1.html
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  {{a}}
</div>
```

Where controller is :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller('ctrl1',function ($scope){$scope.a=1});
```

But the output is :

```
1.html
1
```

**Question**

I did `ng-if="null"` and `null` is a falsy value.
Why does it still display the inner content?

ps - If I put a regular tag :

```
  <p ng-if="null">
        <b>Hello</b>
  </p>
```

It doesn't display it.

Comment: try to inspect what DOM generated by browser with truthy condition. You cannot to nest `<p>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have invalid html, means you can not have nested `p` tag, the inner `p` tag is thrown out.

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

**Below HTML**

```
<p ng-if="null">
    <p ng-include="'1.html'">***</p>
</p>
```

**Rendered As**

```
<p ng-if="null"></p>
<p ng-include="'1.html'">***</p>
```

[**Detailed Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015809/2435473)

Comment: Ouch. you're right. chaning it to span/div - Works:-)

Comment: Why spans? use divs for blocks

Comment: @vp_arth It's just for testing purpose. ( originally it came from this plunker  - http://plnkr.co/edit/MtRpmI?p=info - - where I tested some things , and in order to add values - I changed LI to P).