# Vuejs error when evaluating expression with v-if and v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is what I have:

```
<div v-for="slot in card" class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">{{ slot.name }}</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p v-for="wrestler in slot.wrestlers">
        {{ wrestler.team }}
        <p v-if="true">okay</p>
        {{ wrestler.team }}
    </p>
</div>
```

It throws a warning `Error when evaluating expression "wrestler.team".` The initial wrestler.team is shown and so is the word "okay", but the second wrestler.team throws that warning. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: This would be a very odd behavior indeed... Are you sure its not the next wrestler that is throwing the error because they don't have a `team` property set?

Comment: @Jeff I just checked by changing the bottom `wrestler.team` to `wrestler._id` and still receive the error. Logged data to console and data is showing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Don't nest `<p>` tags. Good post about clarification on nesting `<p>` tags can be found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will).