# How to Remove the nested paragraph tag using Regular Expression in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, simple-html-dom

I am using **Simple Html Dom** for parsing through Html.In this I wasn't able to load `<p>` tag if it is in nested manner

```
<p>Hello there <p>Some Content </p>outer content <p>Some More content</p></p>
```

I don't know how to replace the inner `<p></p>` tags using Regex .

My expected output is :

```
<p>Hello there Some content outer content Some More content</p>
```

Someone please help me in getting this done

Comment: Nested `<p>` tags are not valid and should not be used. That's why you are getting this weird behavior.

Comment: We know that, actually the user who is using the system has entered various nested <p> tags . So we are in need to remove those nested tags with regex in PHP

Comment: Show some code please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your whole problematic `<p>` tag is in a single line, you can use the following regex

`((?!^)<p>)|(<\/p>(?!$))`

`(?!^)<p>)` matches all `<p>` tags excluding the `<p>` in the beginning of the string

`(<\/p>(?!$)` matches all `</p>` tags excluding the `</p>` in the end of the string

you can just replace these captured `<p>` and `</p>`s with null and remove them.

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y33gHa/1)

EDIT:

Since your input is a html file you can try this updated regex

`(<p>)((?!<\/p>).)*?(<p>).*?(<\/p>)`

`(<p>)` searches for `<p>` tag

`((?!<\/p>).)*?(<p>)` captures `<p>` tag inside the first `<p>` tag without any `</p>` tag in between (nested `<p>` tag)

`.*?(<\/p>)` captures the closing tag of the nested `<p>` .

just remove the capture groups 3 and 4 and you have removed the nested

tag. You need to run this again and again till there are no more matches.

you can find the updated regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ycwo96/3)

UPDATE:

Use this regex `(.*<p>)(((?!<\/p>).)*?)(<p>)(.*?)(<\/p>)(.*)`

and replace it with `\1\2\5\7` which will remove the nested tags alone.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ycwo96/4)

Comment: can u see this https://regex101.com/r/ycwo96/2 ?       Actually the regular expression removes the content inside the table content too but my requirement is nested paragraph tag should get removed only if is in nested manner  .

Comment: ah.. can you make that `<p>` in a separate line and run the regex i gave? like you can first replace the first occurrence of `<p>` with `\n<p>`.

Comment: No it wont, It will remove the paragraph tag only if it nested . Actually I am providing the entire html as a input string to Simple Html Dom and if we find "p" tag and incase if the p tag is a nested one then I  am not able to get the entire tags . Nested p tags are creating as separate chunks

Comment: mate the updated Regex is removing some content if the <p> is nested . how to solve that out .

Comment: what content is it removing? the capture groups 3 & 4 capture only the tags and nothing else. as long as you replace only those capture groups it should not remove anything else.

Comment: in the updated regex you can find "<p>Hello there <p>Some Content </p>" is getting removed . can you please explain me how to check that coz i am really new to regex . Can you please update the changes in the working regex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136257/discussion-between-angu-and-abdul-hameed).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function for removing `<p></p>` tags

```
<?php function remove_p($input) {
    $input=str_ireplace('<p>','',$input);
    $input=str_ireplace('</p>','',$input);    
    return "<p>".$input."</p>";  
} 
?>
```

Please see how to use this function:

```
<?php $val = "<p>Hello there <p>Some Content </p>outer content <p>Some More content</p></p>";
echo remove_p($val);
?>
```

Hope, it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Please check my updated code, now, is it ok? or you are trying to say something else.

Comment: it'll work for the input given in the question. but will not work for the input given by OP in the comments of my answer.. The input is a html file sadly.. with all `html` tags not just the `p` tags

Answer (score -1):

Nested p tags are not allowed. In place of that you can use:

```
<p>Hello there <span>Some Content </span>outer content</p>
```

See the below link for more details

[Nesting <p> won't work while nesting <div> will?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will)