# css selector: a class inside another class is not working

Tags: html, css-selectors

I read somewhere a class inside another class is written in this way:
.class1 .class2 { style}.
But I found it counld not work.

For example:

```
<style>
h1 p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.a1 .a2{
     background-color: green;
}
</style>

<h1><p>Welcome to My Homepage</p></h1>

 <p class="a1">
   <p class="a2"> My name is Donald  </p> 
   <p class="a3"> I live in Duckburg.</p>
 </p>
```

As you can see, the following is supposed to be green. But it actually not.

```
<p class="a1"><p class="a2"> My name is Mike  </p> </p>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You can't nest a p inside a p. It's illegal.

Comment: or nest a p inside h1....

Comment: I do not believe it is a duplicate because this specific question was never being asked before. This question itself can benefit other people who may have the same doubt as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `<p/>` elements. Paragraphs can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Change the outer paragraph to a `<div/>` and the styles will be applied correctly:

```css
h1 p {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.a1 .a2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <p>Welcome to My Homepage</p>
</h1>

<div class="a1">
  <p class="a2"> My name is Donald </p>
  <p class="a3"> I live in Duckburg.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with the CSS, but rather the HTML:
You're nesting a `<p>` tag inside of another `<p>` tag.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015809/7024837

Maybe you can try changing `<p class="a1">` into `<span class="a1">`?