# DangerouslySetInnerHtml() showing content from previous page in React

Tags: html, reactjs

Building a site which shows users profiles. When changing from one profile to another, the profile description is getting stuck with the previous users profile data.

For example

1. Visit users profile 1
2. Users profile description reads `User profile 1 description`
3. Visit users profile 2
4. Users profile description reads `User profile 1 description User profile 2 description`

My code is all being run in the render function of my component so should be rerendering when state updates.

```
render(){
    return(
        <h4>Profile 1<h4>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.profile.description}} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `this.props.profile.description` was HTML wrapped in `<p>` tags. This was causing `p` tags to be nested within `p` tags which causes issues as described in this post - [Nesting <p> won't work while nesting <div> will?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will)

Rule of thumb is never use dangerouslySetInnerHTML on a `<p>` tag.

Took me a long time to get to the root cause of this and thought it was worth passing it on.