# Why doesn't my nested paragraph respect font-size styles?

Tags: html, css, font-size

If I have this

```css
.outer {
   font-size: 2em;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    Some Outer Div Text
    <div class="inner">
       Some Inner Div Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Both texts are 32px (16px *2)

However with this HTML:

```
 <p class="outer">
    Some Outer Div Text
    <p class="inner">
       Some Inner Div Text
    </p>
  </p>
```

The outer text is 32px, while the inner text is 16px.

How come the paragraph tag doesn't respect the parent's font-size like the div tag? I thought they would both work the same since they are both block elements?

Here's a JSFiddle in case I'm not clear: https://jsfiddle.net/scottfwalter/2Lrd6tzm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is you can't nest p tags, if you open the console and inspect you will see the 2 p tags are siblings instead of parent/child, therefore there is no inheritance. 
See this answer for more details [Nesting <p> won't work while nesting <div> will?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will)

Comment: Ooh you right.  I didn't realize if you nest paragraph tags they are not really nested.   This explains a lit.

Answer (score 0):

That's because browsers have their's own predefined styles for basic typography. So for example chrome sets `font-size: 16px` for `<p>` but says nothing about `<div>`.
That's why we use normilize.css or reset.css to avoid such missmatching.
Try setting `* {font-size: 16px;}` - this should do the trick

Comment: That does make sense.   I added * {font-size: 16px;} however it doesn't seem to help.   If outer paragraph has a font-size of 2em and the inner paragraph has a font-size of 1em shouldn't they both be 32px.   The div tag works with both the inner and outer as 32px as I expected.  Just curious why the paragraph tag doesn't seem to use the parent paragraph tag as expected.  FYI--I updated the fiddle.   You wouldn't normally nest paragraph tags.  Had someone ask me this the other day and I can't come up with a good answer.