# Unable to use CSS class binding in Angular version 7

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm following [this Angular 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6OP-lPJxgs&index=7&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ) tutorial. But my class bindings throws exception:

[image]

I created the CSS class as

```
.test-regular
{
color:purple;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace
}
```

and in the `customer-component.component.ts` file I created a property

```
 public regularClass="test-regular";
```

and in the html template I'm using it as

```
 <h2 [class]="regularClass">Hiya Everyone</h2>
```

This is how it's suggested in the tutorial. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The error tells you that the problem is with a p tag. Post the template. Or even better, post a stackblitz reproducing the problem. Apparently, you've put the <h2> inside a <p>, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: Yes I understand. Since I was nesting <p> tags, the exception was thrown as nesting of <p> is not allowed.

Comment: @RaidaAdn nested p tag is allowed.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz no, it isn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will

Comment: @RaidaAdn  nested p tags works on normal html. I believe however i doesn't work in angular. you can try it on by creating a normal html page or on W3School

Comment: You've already asked that question, and I already answered. You're free to not use Stackoverflow if you don't like its rules. Instead of complaining, try to make your question better, to read error messages, to provide the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Since I used `<h2>` inside `<p>` which is not correct since  The  tags are logical tags which are used specifically to convey section headings.I got the error.

Even nesting of `<p>` is also not allowed. Since `<p>` are block level element and it cannot contain itself.
Hence I updated my html as follows.

```
<p>  
<input [id]="divid" type="text" value="Cajole"/><br>
<input id="{{divid}}" type="text" value="Cajole"/><br>
<input [disabled]="isdisabled" type=text value="Cajole"/><br> 
</p>
<div [class]="regularClass">Hiya Everyone</div>
```

Hope this helps to anyone with no css knowledge.