# Why p:first-child pseudo class does not apply to p element's first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

CSS Pseudo Class selector(first-child) for p tag applies to all p that are immediate first child to their parent why not p tag that is immediate first element of p itself.

```css
p:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>This P is body's first Child.</p>
    <p>This is body's second child.</p>

    <div>
        <p> This P is div's first Child </p>
        <p> This is div's second child.</p>
    </div>

    <p>
        <p> This P is P's first child :: Why it does not get pseudo class</p>
        <p> This is P's second child </p>
    </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Nested paragraphs are invalid HTML. Virtually every browser will attempt to fix that and change your code to `<p>
        </p><p> This P is P's first child :: Why it does not get pseudo class</p>
        <p> This is P's second child </p>
    <p></p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<p>` tags cannot be nested in HTML. This is because they only exist to format text as.. well.. a paragraph, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will).

In short, any open `<p>` tag simply closes whatever the last `<p>` to be opened was, regardless of syntax.