# Nested v-for loops using p tag doesn't work in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I want to nest 2 v-for loops. It should be quite simple, but it's not working and I have no clue why.

When I loop through the users and display their names, this is working fine. When I take the first element from the session-array and display it's name, this is also working fine.

However, when I want to cycle through the session-array in a nested v-for loop, the array seems to be empty. Why is this?

```
<p v-for="entry in user">
    {{entry.name}} //this is working fine
    {{entry.session[0].name}} //this is also working fine, so "session" is an array with elements that have the property "name"
    <p v-for="session_entry in entry.session"> //this v-for is not executed, as if entry.session would be empty
        {{session_entry.name}}
    </p>
</p>
```

```
  data: {
    user: [{
      name: 'test2name', 
      session:[
        {name:'sessionname'},
        {name:'sessionname2'}
      ]
    }]
  }
```

According to this code snippet it should be working. What did I miss?
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/vuejs+nested+v-for

Comment: Nesting `p` tags is not allowed in HTML - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i change the outer  `p` to `div` it works fine as below :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: [{
      name: 'test2name',
      session: [{
          name: 'sessionname'
        },
        {
          name: 'sessionname2'
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <div v-for="entry in user">
    {{entry.name}}
    <p v-for="session_entry in entry.session">
      {{session_entry.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, then it works. Has anyone got a clue why this is? Is this a bug or a design choice of vue?

Comment: I think that `p` doesn't accept other elements as children

Answer (score 1):

[Nesting p tags is not allowed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will)

Vue compiler (which processes your template) somehow knows this and compiles into something like this:

```html
<p v-for="entry in user">
    {{entry.name}}
    {{entry.session[0].name}}
</p>
<p v-for="session_entry in entry.session">
    {{session_entry.name}}
</p>
```

...which leads to an error "entry is undefined but referenced during render"

You can check yourself by pasting your templete into [vue-compiler-online](https://magiccwl.github.io/vue-compiler-online/) and look at the AST on the right

BTW you should always check your browsers Dev Tool console for useful messages like this when something doesn't work as expected...

Comment: Ah, thank you. Now I know why this was happening. Actually the error "entry is undefined but referenced during render" was first thrown, but I didn't understand it. With some changes in the code the error disappeared, but it was still not rendered.