# Why appear <p> tag around <img> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<p>
    <img src="media/icons/info_ticket.png"></img>
    <h3>Ticket #TKMA<span><?php echo $_GET['CRy3sjzZOJyXE']; ?></span></h3>
</p>
```

And when I apply CSS to change the style of the `img` it doesn't work! So, I inspected the element and I found this:

```
<p>
    <img src="media/icons/info_ticket.png">
</p>
<h3>Ticket #TKMA<span>17</span></h3>
<p></p>
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: `<h3>` is a block-level element and should never be inside a `<p>`.

Comment: ok, 4 answers exactly equal, why not just upvote the first who posted?

Comment: Haha, and the feeding frenzy of answers and even crazier frenzy of editing has begun!

Comment: @ryan :( thats true and sad, ppl answer as quickly as they can, and after this they make the changes to fit the question, its the "first" syndrome.

Comment: @Ark Well.. upvote for all but the answer that post links to reference.. is choosen :P (don't hate me)

Comment: @SoldierCorp haha, go ahead, they giv it right, they deserve it, for future reference its better. im gonna upvote too

Comment: @Ark, haha.Nonetheless, mine was never modified. A simple question requires a simple, to the point explanation and that's the route I took ;).

Comment: @DennisRongo ok you got my attention, +1 for you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Because your HTML is invalid](http://html5.validator.nu/). [`<p>` elements can only contain phrasing content.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

See [List of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside P element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element/9852381#9852381)

Comment: ^^ was the first to respond, and lists the most resources.

Comment: Why does this validates correctly then on the validator page http://html5.validator.nu/
`<p>Hello world<em>Test</em><img src="http://google.com/asd/cp" alt="Description"/></p>`

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because, an `H` element inside a `<p>` element isn't valid so the browser corrects it by pulling it out.

Answer (score 2):

Because having an `<h3>` inside a `<p>` is invalid html

The browser is doing its version of auto-correct.

Answer (score 2):

An `<h3>` tag is not valid inside a `<p>` tag.  Your editor is "fixing" it by moving the header outside the paragraph, leaving only the image in the paragraph.