# jQuery .on efficiency

Tags: jquery, event-handling, event-bubbling

Is the first .on function more efficient than second one ?

```
$( "div.container" ).on( "click", "p", function(){
});

$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function(){
});
```

Regards

Comment: Probably, since the event won't have to propagate as many times to get to the `p.container` as it will to get to the `body`.

Comment: *"Hierarchical selectors can often be avoided simply by attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document. For example, instead of `$( "body" ).on( "click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment )` use `$( "#commentForm" ).on( "click", ".addNew", addComment )`."* [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation itself about **[jQuery: .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**:

> jQuery can process simple selectors of the form tag#id.class very quickly when they are used to filter delegated events. So, "#myForm", "a.external", and "button" are all fast selectors. **Delegated events that use more complex selectors, particularly hierarchical ones, can be several times slower--although they are still fast enough for most applications. Hierarchical selectors can often be avoided simply by attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document.** For example, instead of $( "body" ).on( "click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment ) use $( "#commentForm" ).on( "click", ".addNew", addComment ).

Answer (score 1):

The narrower the first selector is, the better the performance is.

But the first example won't work I guess, because you are monitoring all the `<p>`s container in `<p>`s having `container` class, and a `<p>`cannot contain another `<p>`, due to being a [phrasing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element).

Comment: my bad, i'll change it

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as the browser only has to monitor one paragraph for click events as opposed to the entire page.