# Browser behaves strangely when loading HTML from MySQL database into a contenteditable tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-chrome

I have a simple code in my php file like this:

```
echo "<p id='additional-info' contenteditable='true'>".$tag_data->additional_info."</p>";
```

$tag_data->additional_info is data that gets loaded from the database. The data I am trying to load in this case is very simple, it is:

```
line 1 <p>line 2</p><p>line 3</p>
```

Now this is where the problem arises, I would expect the browser (Google Chrome in my case) to output this as such:

```
echo "<p id='additional-info' contenteditable='true'>line 1 <p>line 2</p><p>line 3</p></p>";
```

But instead, for some reason it outputs this:

```
<p id="additional-info" contenteditable="true">line 1 </p>
<p>line 2</p>
<p>line 3</p>
<p></p>
```

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here -> [P element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) according to it :

```
The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).
```

So that's Chrome displays it in this way.

Not sure what your idea is but you may want to use a `<div class="text">...</div>` and apply any appropriate styling.

**EDIT:** Have a further look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element) has a a list of elements allowed inside `P tag` [HTML5]

Comment: Thank you Boris, that worked. Can't believe I over looked that.