# p tag not containing ul tag

Tags: html, css

I was just working on creating a simple address container and what I had in my HTML was just the following simple markup:

```
<p class="address">
    <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.address {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Now somehow the `<p>` element does not contain the `ul` and neither is the box-shadow applied to the `p` tag , but when I replace the `p` tag with a `div` tag, everything works find. The div contains the `ul` (as can be seen in the inspect elements) and also the div has a box-shadow. I have checked this in both FF and Chrome and have no idea of why is this glitch occurring.

Comment: For your reference `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside`. Consider using `div` istead.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik No, why?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik i dont understand what you mean by that. assuming address is just a text, it doesnt have to be included in`<p>` as must.

Comment: @MrLister  , this article http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/ and this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/address says use <p> whenever address is not relevant !

Comment: Anyway, to answer the technicalities, the `</p>` end tag is _optional_, so what happens when the parser sees the `<ul>` it knows that the `<p>` should end. And it does! So the `<p>` is completely empty and that's why it doesn't get drawn. No margins, no shadow.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Those pages describe the `<address>` element, which is not applicable in this case. You're not using `<address>` elements.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks ! i guess that answers my question and yeah ! i am not useing address , but if you cheeck the links i added , it says "use p" where address is not applicable !

Comment: You _can_ use a `<p>` if you want, you just can't put an `<ul>` inside it. So if you really need the `<ul>`, you can't use the `<p>`. If you really need the `<p>`, you can't use the `<ul>`.

Comment: Ok that about sums it up , great !! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the answer from a similar question: [List of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside P element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element)

Only phrasing content can be in between the `<p>` tag and is described as follows:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements
>   that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing
>   content form paragraphs.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that says "can" instead of "should". "Should" doesn't imply that it is literally impossible for a p to contain a ul or any other flow content; "can" does.

Comment: @BoltClock - of course, that's only a limitation of the HTML parser. It doesn't apply to the XML parser or to DOM methods.

Comment: @Alohci: As evidenced by the newest answer. Well I'll be - I was under the impression that this limitation applied to DOM methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` elements are not legally allowed inside `p` element.

Reference : 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

Comment: "Legally" isn't really a term most people use when discussing HTML standards?

Comment: @codyogden - True, although the HTML 4.01 spec uses some variant of "legal" 40 times to describe validity requirements. For example, [boolean attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("p").append("<ul>        <li>hello</li>        <li>hello</li>        <li>hello</li>    </ul>");
```

```css
.address {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="address">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**it's strange behave that you can do this thing by java script As append  tag to

tag using jQuery Or java script This will works **

it may issue with rendering time it also strange behave with IE browser.
try out this thing ing IE browser also.

Answer (score -3):

Even though you kept `ul` inside `P` its not rendering as you think in the browser.
Please see the below screenshot for reference[image]

Comment: as per link 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element
we should not keep ul as nested inside p