# How can do ng-for in ng-for angularjs 2.0?

Tags: angular

This code below does not work! How can i do `ng-for` inside a  `ng-for`?

```
<ul *ng-for="#item of items">
    <li *ng-for="#task of item.tasks">{{task.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why doesn't work? Do you get some error? You'll need to be more specific and if it is possible to reproduce the error in a plnkr.

Comment: Did you try with a non-nested `ng-for`, or doesn't that work either? If it doesn't work, I would try to get that working first, otherwise @alexpods could have a point.

Comment: not-nested works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/af2v6Dn2fYTzToTH6iAs?p=preview

Comment: @AigarsBeinarovičs I've updated answer one more time

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible errors: you might forgot to specify `NgFor` or `CORE_DIRECTIVES` in `directives` property of the `View` decorator:

```js
import {Component, View, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component()
@View({
  template: `...`,
  directives: [NgFor] // <- You might forgot to do this
})
export class SomeCompoennt { ... }
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/af2v6Dn2fYTzToTH6iAs?p=preview) also

**UPD** Problem with [this your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/af2v6Dn2fYTzToTH6iAs?p=preview)

The problem is that `p` (paragraph element) cannot contain block elements. See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

So browser converts any nested `p`s:

```
<p>
  <p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </p>
</p>
```

into flat structure:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

So code:

```
<p *ng-for="#person of peopleService.people">
  {{person.name}}
  <table>
      <tr *ng-for='#hobby of person.hobbies'>
          <td>{{hobby}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</p>
```

will be converted by browser into:

```
<p *ng-for="#person of peopleService.people">
  {{person.name}}
</p>
<table>
  <tr *ng-for='#hobby of person.hobbies'>
    <td>{{hobby}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Of course `person` is `undefined` in this situation.

Comment: This thing doesn't like `<p>`s apparently. With `<div>`s works pretty well http://plnkr.co/edit/QlW890DprENDdhOrcxeB?p=preview

Comment: Ooh, thanks to you, Eric, I've understood what is going on. Look at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). **<p> cannot contain block-level elements**

Comment: Yes, I asked in gitter and I was told the same. [Here's a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) of `block-level elements`. This list includes `table` which was inside `<p>` in the OP's plnkr originally.

Comment: Yeah, but for html5 it's even more tricky. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element#9852381)

Comment: @alexpods as you already know, `ng-for` has become `ngFor` and `#` became `let`. So `<p *ngFor="let person of peopleService.people">`