# ng-repeat inside ng-if rendering despite falsey ng-if expression

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` that iterates over an array of objects. Each object has a `type` property and a `contents` array. Inside the `ng-repeat`, I would like to display the `contents` array different depending on the `type` of the object, so I am conditionally displaying content with an `ng-if`.

The problem is it appears the `ng-repeat` is executing and rendering regardless of if the `ng-if` is truthy or falsey, and that when `ng-if` is falsey that it's not removing the `ng-repeat` DOM elements.

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the implementation, or if these angular directives aren't meant to be used quite like this - or if there's a better way to solve this problem in angular.

Below are the snippets, and here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FZQ5CM8UFOepNIHHuTD4?p=preview

**The HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="FunkyCtrl as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="thing in vm.twoThings">

    <p ng-if="thing.type === 'apple'">
      <span>Type: {{thing.type}}</span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="content in thing.contents">Food: {{content.stuff}}</li>
      </ul>
    </p>

    <p ng-if="thing.type === 'dog'">
      <span>Type: {{thing.type}}</span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="content in thing.contents">Guts: {{content.stuff}}</li>
      </ul>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

**The script:**

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('funkyStuff', []);
  angular.module('funkyStuff').controller('FunkyCtrl', FunkyCtrl);

  function FunkyCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.twoThings = [
      {
        type: 'apple',
        contents: [
          {
            stuff: 'apple slices'
          },
          {
            stuff: 'juice'
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'dog',
        contents: [
          {
            stuff: 'bones'
          },
          {
            stuff: 'meat'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
})(angular);
```

**Expected Output:**

Type: apple

- Food: apple slices
- Food: juice

Type: dog

- Guts: bones
- Guts: meat

**Actual Output:**

Type: apple

- Food: apple slices
- Food: juice
- Guts: apple slices
- Guts: juice
- Food: bones
- Food: meat

Type: dog

- Guts: bones
- Guts: meat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your HTML is invalid. The `ul` element is not allowed inside `p`.

If you inspect the rendered HTML you will notice that the `ul` has been rendered outside the `p` (might depend on the browser implementation of course).

Replace `p` with for example `div` and you will get the result you expect.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/pBVZ4jIJ5qzRsa8xZbud?p=preview

If you want to know which elements are allowed inside `p` you can find a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element).

Comment: Wow, whoops! Thanks!