# Why can't I use a heading tag inside a p tag and style it with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
              div p h1 {
                  background-color: red;
              }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p><h1>hello2</h1></p> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is basic HTML (or any other markup language). You should separate the paragraph from the heading element. If you want to put a sub heading below your main heading, I suggest you do something like `<div><h1>Main heading</h1><p>Sub heading</p></div>` It's important to CLOSE the html elements before creating new ones. Unless it's a div, span or section, which is meant for gathering topically similar elements. A lot more could be said, but I suggest you read more about HTML and markup language.

Comment: but I can add a <p> tag inside <h> tag, like <h1><p>hello</p></h1>, I thought reverse was also possible

Comment: Added a new answer with some more details and some good references / reading material for you (and for everyone else visiting this question)! Take a look, and I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 14):

I think thats why:

> The `<p>` tag can only contain inline elements. The header tags are block-level elements, and cannot go inside `<p>` tags even when you style them to display inline.

Comment: but I can do something like <h1><p>h1</p></h1>

Comment: Actually you can't. According to the: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html#h1 You can only use [Phrasing elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) inside h tags

Answer (score 3):

This is basic HTML (or any other markup language). You should separate the `paragraph, <p></p>` from the `heading, <h1></h1>` element.

If you want to put a sub heading below your main heading, I suggest you do something like

```
<div>
    <h1>Main heading</h1>
    <h2>Smaller heading</h2>
    <p>Some information or a quote</p>
</div>
```

It's important to CLOSE the html elements before creating new ones. Unless it's a [div](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp), [span](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) or [section](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp) which is meant for gathering topically similar elements.

A lot more could be said, but I suggest you get ahead and read more about HTML and markup language. A good place to start is http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp …

If you specifically wonder what elements can be nested inside a paragraph check out the answer on this question: [List of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside P element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element)

Comment: Closing `</p>` tags are completely optional.  It's not important to close them.  The spec says that they are implicitly closed whenever a new block-element is opened.

Comment: That's true, but since he/she is still in the semantic syntax phase of HTML, I thought it was best to keep it out from the answer. It's still best practice to close all elements even though browsers will display it correctly, so I would still recommend OP to close the paragraph. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Having a `H1` element inside a `p` element is invalid mark-up. When the browser encounters this mark-up, it tries to fix it automatically by moving the `H1` outside of the `p`. Once this has occurred, the selector no longer matches anything.

Use the [W3C markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/check) to ensure the validity of your document

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <h1>hello2</h1>
   <p>im the best</p> 
</div>
```

Because your header is like the title of an article - you don't put the title in a paragraph. Using the `<p>` tags, you're just writing the content for the article, so you wont be able to style a header tag in a `p` tag as you will most likely be styling your header and content differently

Answer (score -1):

If you are having issue with HTML Structure See the Lynda HTML5 course really worth Your Time It Clarifies how to structure your document. Along with reasons why. You will have a better understanding of What is Style and what is structure which most people struggle with I would include myself.

Also has links to the official web standards "World Wide Web Consortium", Yes I know it's a paid for service but it help me avoid or understand why HTML and CSS react the way it does when you move element in to invalid place.

Understand that h1-h6 Tag are not meant for styling as I previously thought from my earlier days in HTML. Yes we used them because it seemed to make since or easyer to target with CSS. But the h1-h6 are more to structure of importance off the section or content on the page. I would use a div if it's or a span or Bold tag.

Great resource is developer.mozilla.org

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure
Here is a good example: Of structure from the link above!

```html
<body>
     <!-- Main header used across all the pages website -->
        <header>
          <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
           <form>
             <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search query">
             <input type="submit" value="Go!">
           </form>
         </nav>
        <!-- Here is our page's main content -->
        <main>
          <!-- It contains an article -->
          
          <article>

<!-----------***** As you can see the h1-h6 is for structure not style****** -->
            <h2>Article heading              Rank2</h2>
              <p>This is Paragraph</p>

                <h3>subsection               Rank3</h3>
                   <p>This is Paragraph </p>
                   <p>This is Paragraph </p>

                    <h4>Another subsection   Ranked</h4>
                       <p>This is Paragraph </p>

                <h3>Another subsection       Ranked</h3>
                   <p>This is Paragraph </p>
                   <p>This is Paragraph </p>
          </article>
          <aside>
            <h2>Related</h2>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">beside the seaside</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">beside the sea</a></li>
            </ul>
          </aside>

        </main>

        <!-- main footer that is used across all the pages of site -->

        <footer>
          <p>©Copyright 2050 by nobody. All rights reversed.</p>
        </footer>
```

**But really Check out the Lynda HTML 5 Essentials Tutorials!
When a document it's structured correctly it's readable and more applications and devices. Like Readers.**