# Styling does not all apply

Tags: css

I want to override the css of `<h1>` and `<h2>` using selector (specific using selector only) but it's not working. It's getting only applied to one class only `<h1>` color changes to green not `<h2>`.

Please help can someone tell me where I am wrong. Please help!

```css
.temp {
  color: blue;
}
.temp2 {
  color: red;
}
p .temp,.temp2{
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hi there this is a test page
<h1 class="temp">heading inside p tag</h1>
<h2 class="temp2">2nd heading inside p tag</h2>

</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use a heading tag inside a p tag and style it with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891822/why-cant-i-use-a-heading-tag-inside-a-p-tag-and-style-it-with-css)

Comment: You're not suppost to have `h` elements inside a `p`!

Comment: yes I can do this using .temp, .temp2 but i want to specifically use p selector( like temp temp2 class that is contained inside a p tag specifically.

Comment: Please read the second linked post. This is against the HTML spec, so you just can't/shouldn't do that.

Comment: your html is invalid you can't include an h1 inside a p [check](https://caninclude.glitch.me/caninclude?child=h1&parent=p)

Comment: thanks guys got my mistake now i have wrapped h1 and h2 inside div now its working fine. thanks for your help all much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```css
.temp {
  color: blue;
}
.temp2 {
  color: red;
}
div .temp,
div .temp2{
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
    hi there this is a test page
    <h1 class="temp">heading inside p tag</h1>
    <h2 class="temp2">2nd heading inside p tag</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ninja. but I have a doubt I am new to css I want to ask why we need to  write div with temp2

why we can't do like this div .temp,.temp2 { some styling}

Answer (score -1):

```css
.temp {
  color: blue;
}
.temp2 {
  color: red;
}
span .temp, .temp2{
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<span>
  hi there this is a test page
<h1 class="temp">heading inside p tag</h1>
<h2 class="temp2">2nd heading inside p tag</h2>
</span>
```

## Answer:

- putting `h1`/`h2` content inside `p` is invalid (You might have noticed in Stack overflow's snippet editor)
- Imagine having a huge heading inside small paragraph
- so change to `span`/`div`/etc (in *html+css*)

Answer (score -2):

You have missed to mention the paragraph element for temp2

```css
.temp {
  color: blue;
}
.temp2 {
  color: red;
}
p .temp,p .temp2{
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hi there this is a test page
<h1 class="temp">heading inside p tag</h1>
<h2 class="temp2">2nd heading inside p tag</h2>

</p>
```

Comment: inline styling gets the highest priority, after that selector based on id of an element gets high priority.

EG : 
.temp {
  color: blue;
}
.temp2 {
  color: red;
}

<p>
  hi there this is a test page
<h1 class="temp" style="color:green;">heading inside p tag</h1>
<h2 class="temp2" style="color:green;">2nd heading inside p tag</h2>

</p>

! important is not an nice idea

Comment: your solution is not woorking.

Comment: I have updated your answer to include a snippet. Now you can see that it won't work like that.