# How to fix 2 types of W3C Validator Errors

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is my validator result](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ucuzeloboost.com%2Ffiyatsorgulama.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

I need help fixing these 3 types of errors:

1. " there is no attribute "
2. " document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag "
3. "  reference to entity "degerdiv" for which no system identifier could be generated "

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And what is your source code?

Comment: @reporter the source code is already provided in validator.

Comment: @Shahil Source code that shows the problem must be posted here.

Comment: If you look at the validation output returned it gives you the information you require. For issue 1 it gives you the following url: https://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-flash. Your second issue is nesting a div in a paragraph.

Comment: Sadly im a newb in coding and can't really understand what you guys saying. I understood the second issue but need help with issue 1 and 3. Thanks !

Comment: By the way, nesting a div in a paragraph wont work or its just a wrong usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "there is no attribute"

This means you have used an attribute name that doesn't exist in the HTML specs. In your case it was on a [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) tag. The only valid attributes for a `<meta>` tag are `name`, `content`, `http-equiv`, and `charset`.

### "document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag"

This means you have a `<div>` inside some element that doesn't allow a `<div>` according to the HTML specs. In this case, it is a `<p>` tag, which only allows [**these tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852381/5743988) to be nested inside.

### "reference to entity "degerdiv" for which no system identifier could be generated"

This is caused by an unencoded ampersand `&` triggering the HTML parser to search for an HTML entity with the name `degerdiv`. In your case, the location was inside your JavaScript code. This error can be ignored, or you can encode the ampersand as `&amp;`, or you can move your JS into an external file.

An additional solution is to use an object for the `data` value, as jQuery supports an [object with key/value pairs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server) as a readable alternative to providing a query string.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "fiyaturet.php",
  data: {
    deger: deger,
    deger2: deger2,
    sunucu: sunucu,
    degerdiv: degerdiv,
    degerdiv2: degerdiv2
  },
  success: function(ajax1cevap) {
    $('#fiyat').html(ajax1cevap);
  }
});
```

Comment: So placing <div> inside some element that doesn't allow a <div> wont work or it will work but its wrong usage ?

Comment: It is possible to use it but you may find odd behavior in certain browsers and it's not semantically correct