# nth-child of id element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to highlight 'The second paragraph' of p id="dd". Can I make it with nth-child? When I add "#dd" in styles, it stops to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#dd p:nth-child(3) {
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="de">
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</p>
<p id="dd">
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to apply styles correctly. But your `HTML` is invalid. You can't have a `<p>` inside another `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

As Muhammad Usman kindely noted above,

**You need to Change** the "*parent*" `<p>` to a `<div>` and **it will work**.

```css
#dd p:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="de">
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="dd">
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

p inside a p is not allowed. Make a div and add the paragraphs in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/8fh108cL/

The relevant change in the snippet.

```
<div id="de">
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="dd">
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't append paragraphs inside a paragraph. Please refer to this really good post [from Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element).

Your approach is right, you can use `#dd:nth-child(n)` where n is the child you are targeting with your CSS rules.