# Why does a form styled as "inline-block" work in "div" but not in "p"?

Tags: html, css

**Following code for a 'form' wrapped in a 'div' works correct:**

```
<div>
    Please logout with a Click:
    <form style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="val1">
        <button type="submit">Logout-Button</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Note:** The form is styled as `inline-block`. The code is placed in a `<div>`.

Wrapped in the `<div>` this works proper and on the page this show up correct in one line:

> Please logout with a Click: [Logout-Button]

**But changing the wrapper from 'div' to 'p' leads to an unexpected behaviour:**

When the form is wrapped in a `<p>` instead of the `<div>` the button breaks to a new line:

The code ...

```
<p>
    Please logout with a Click:
    <form style="display: inline-block;"> ... </form>
</p>
```

Results in ...

> Please logout with a Click:
>   [Logout-Button]

(Same behaviour when I use `inline` instead of `inline-block` to style the form.)

**I wonder about:**

- As `<div>` and `<p>` are both Block-Elements: what is the basic reason for this unexpected different behaviour in `<div>` and `<p>`?
- Does anyone know a simple CSS-Solution to make the *'inline-view'* of the form/button working in a 'p-tag'?

Thanks for any hints and answers!

Comment: why would you want a form in a p tag? a p tag is for paragraphs, a.k.a - text. Forms are not texts ...

Comment: The form is not inside the p. Paragraphs have optional end tags, so the browser treats this as having an invisible `</p>` just before the `<form`. So the answer to your question is, no, there is no simple CSS solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway? What would using a `p` do that cannot be done with a `div`? If you tell us that, we can come up with a solution. Assigning margins to the `div` for instance...

Comment: It is invalid to put a form inside a p tag anyway - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p have a look at the permitted content

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: Indeed is not about a 'must-have-solution' but it is technical curiosity for the basic reason. Concerning 'forms are not texts': full ACK. But in this special(!) case 'Click the button [logut-button]' the contextual meaning of the whole form IMHO changes to a simple text-element ... but this is a very personal(!) interpretation and should not be the discussion.

Comment: @Brebber Then just put the `p` in the `form` and you can put the `button` in the `p`. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p tag is for paragraph. When using the form tag inside the p tag what it does is its just close the previous opening p and then open it again after the closing form tag. (At leat on Google Chrome) Maybe there are some official documentation for that online but cant find any.

i.e.

this

```
<p>
Please logout with a Click: 
<form style="display: inline-block; ">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="val1">
    <button type="submit">Logout-Button</button>
</form>
```

when rendered will turn into

```
    <body>
    <p>Please logout with a Click: </p>
<form style="display: inline-block; ">
            <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="val1">
            <button type="submit">Logout-Button</button>
        </form>
    <p></p>
    </body>
```

Hope it helps you understand. Check the html code on chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element

Comment: absolutely usefull thanks @TemaniAfif

Comment: Thx for all and quick answers. Understood as reason: general definition for the tags.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Thx for the very helpful link and hint for duplicate. Didn't find it when I searched for the theme before.