# Why I can't get multiple value of inputs using getElementsByTagName()?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get into a set of inputs values using TagName and store only even numbered ones in a table with the position. It seems like there is an error.

```js
function call() {
  var v = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var s = '<table border = 1><tr><td>position<td>value</tr>';
  for (var i = 0; i <= v.length; i++) {

    var p = v[i].value;
    console.log(p);

    if (p % 2 === 0) {

      s += '<tr><td>' + i + '<td>' + p + '</tr>';
    }
  }
  s += '</table>'
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = s;
}
```

```html
<p>elm 1 : <input type="texte" name="" value="10"></p>
<p>elm 2 : <input type="texte" name="" value="12"></p>
<p>elm 3 : <input type="texte" name="" value="10"></p>
<p>elm 4 : <input type="texte" name="" value="12"></p>
<button onclick="call()">calculat</button>
<hr>
<p id="result"></p>
```

[jsBin for my code](https://jsbin.com/buhupoc/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: In your `for` loop, replace `i <= v.length` by `i < v.length`, you're doing 1 extra loop. And you're missing 2 closing `</td>`, inside that loop

Comment: ... and 2 at the beginning, too. Also, you're inserting a `table` inside a `p`, which is [not valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852381/1913729). And in your page HTML, `type="texte"` should be `type="text"`

Comment: hi, think you for helping me, just i want to start from 1 in position

Comment: So your problem is that the numbers are off by one?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but you should probably start with `i = 0`. JavaScript arrays start with 0, so it's easier on the code side if you always start with 0. At the bottom where you generate the table, you can replace the `+i+` with `+(i+1)+`. That will make the position numbers look normal (by starting with 1).

Comment: oook think you very much i do that but i missed the ()  ...hahaha im sorry im super beginner dont be angry plz....think you

Comment: Since you're a beginner, I'll give you a link to explain more about why the () is necessary: [Javascript + sign concatenates instead of giving sum of variables](/a/5961029/5764553)

Comment: think you very much it helpfull