# Wish to display <p> text in 3 line with left align and rest of the text as ellipsis

Tags: css

Wish to display `<p>` text in 3 line with left align and rest of the text as ellipsis ( Please refer desired output image).
But currently the below css display in single line with ellipsis as below.
Could someone please advise how to make the text display in 3 line and rest in ellipsis ?

**Actual Ouput:**

[image]

```css
.textElipsis {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}
```

```html
<p class='textElipsis'>
  Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Print the whole text here. Ideas are always usefull...
  <div>
    <code>{textCode}</code>
  </div>
</p>
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-webkit-line-clamp` for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

For browser support see:

https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp

Please also note, that you cannot put a `div` inside a `p` tag. It is not valid html.

[List of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside P element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element)

```css
.textElipsis {
  width: 250px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px dashed tomato;
}

.code {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class='textElipsis'>
  Best heading added here. The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Print the whole text here. Ideas are always usefull...
  <code class="code">{textCode}</code>
</p>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is working now...appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-clamp` for this.

```
.textElipsis {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it is not supported by all the browser, you can try it or you can use [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) for the same.

Comment: Thank you, I am using chrome, but still i can see its not applying as per above css

Comment: Can you please share code repo with jsfiddle or any other platform