# Invalid HTML only when wrapped with a paragraph

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a clickable tile using an anchor tag, this code seems to work just fine:

```
<a href="#">
  <span>label</span>
  <address>
    address detail
  </address>
</a>
```

However, when I wrap this block with a paragraph, the code breaks - when I "inspect element" in Chrome (v116, latest) the address tag is moved outside of the paragraph.

I believe I should be able to place an `address` element ([or any other block level element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828032/4008056)) inside an anchor element, but if I switch out the `address` element for an inline element the problem is resolved.

Is this valid HTML? Why does it work except when wrapped with a paragraph?

Comment: I find that the [W3C Validator Service](https://validator.w3.org/) is good at saying why some piece of HTML is invalid.

Comment: good idea - I found the problem, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Because address is not a phrasing content https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake - I had a broken template tag at the top of my page which broke the html doctype. Somewhat interestingly, I saw no evidence of this until I encountered this issue.

I believe the problem was that all my other code was still valid, but the broken doctype meant the page was interpreted as HTML 4 instead of 5 (block level elements inside an anchor element only became valid in html5).

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's invalid to wrap an `<address>` with a `<p>`. The [paragraph element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) cannot contain block-level elements. Even if the doctype is HTML5, when a parser encounters an address element before an open paragraph is closed it will automatically close the paragraph.