# child selector is not selecting

Tags: css, css-selectors

By not working I mean I'm obviously misunderstanding how it's used. I want to select the pre tag only if it's inside of description.

```css
p.description > pre{color:red}
```

```html
<p class="description">
    <pre> adsfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asf sd f</pre>
</p>
```

The parent of pre in this case is p.description so why doesn't this select it?  I've looked at many other posts here and I don't see what I could possibly be doing wrong.

Comment: `text-color: red;`?

Comment: If you look you will see that the `<pre>` has been unnested from your `<p>`. This is probably because it's not valid to nest the element there?

Comment: The HTML has an error. You can’t have a block level element like pre as a child of a p element.

Comment: Isn't P a block level element itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371787/can-i-have-a-pre-tag-inside-a-p-tag-in-tumblr

Comment: Yes p is, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p for permitted content.

Comment: @AHaworth it's not really about block element, it's more about the nature of the element (it's a html issue, not a CSS one).

Comment: You can always check your markup with official [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/check) when in doubt.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don’t follow, I said it was the HTML that had an error. Then the OP asked if p is a block level element.

Comment: @AHaworth you said "You can’t have a block level element like pre as a child of a p element", it's not really about the block part, otherwise changing the display of pre to inline will make the code valid but it won't. The HTML nature of pre (not its display) is not permitted inside p

Comment: Ah, yes, I used the wrong phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Do you explicitly need the parent container to be a `p`?

If not, try changing it to a `div`:

```css
div.description pre {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
    <pre> adsfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asf sd f</pre>
</div>
```