# Wrapping a DIv in a Pre tag

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code with me:

```
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-3">   
    <div id="_idContainer063" class="Code-Box">
                    <p class="Code">$.ajax({</p>
                    <p class="Code">  type: “GET”,</p>
                    <p class="Code">  url: “/myurl”,</p>
                    <p class="Code">  dataType: “json” // text, html, xml</p>
                    <p class="Code">})</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I use CSS to automatically wrap all div with class='Code-box' in a `<pre>` tag?

**Expected Output:**

```
<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-3">
      <pre><div id="_idContainer063" class="Code-Box">
                            <p class="Code">$.ajax({</p>
                            <p class="Code">  type: “GET”,</p>
                            <p class="Code">  url: “/myurl”,</p>
                            <p class="Code">  dataType: “json” // text, html, xml</p>
                            <p class="Code">})</p>
    </div></pre>
</div>
```

Also I want **no space** between the lines of all para inside a div with class='Code-box'.

How can I achieve the two requirements?

Comment: don't use other elements inside the `pre` tag. just decode whatever the code you have and paste it inside the `pre` tag. it will look like code only.

Comment: I have thousands of code blocks of those div elements and instead of doing it manually, I am thinking if it is possible to use a master css that automatically wraps all div with class='Code-box' in <pre>

Comment: As the answer from Nabil states, CSS cannot add tags to the DOM, however, you may be able to process a `div` like a `pre` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219219/how-to-change-a-span-to-look-like-a-pre-with-css - oh...I see he updated his answer with the CSS.

Comment: Yes that should do but the line spacings do not go http://jsbin.com/dikeraqese/1/edit?css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief answer, no, you can't wrap an elements with new elements with CSS, CSS doesn't act in the DOM.

But you can still you do this to make you `div` look like `pre`:

```
.Code-Box {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

To remove spaces in `p`, you remove margins and paddings:

```
.Code-Box p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: what does this css do?

Comment: Ok Nabil, this looks like it does work. But hte spacings do not go http://jsbin.com/dikeraqese/1/edit?css,output

Comment: Ha! Do we have a CSS champ badge here. Please give this gentleman one! Thanksssss!

Comment: One last issue. At some places, I am getting &#9; in my html which causes unnecessary spaces. Is there a way I can remove that.  http://jsbin.com/xivuwexoje/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Hitz AFAIK there is not way to do this with CSS