# Render tree in html preserving white space

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to render the following tree preserving white spaces properly?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
└─--[TaskD-{'a': '0.28', 'b': '0.296', 'c': '0.364', 'e': '0.486'}]
    |---[TaskC-{'a': '0.28', 'b': '0.296', 'c': '0.364'}]
    |   └─--[TaskB-{'a': '0.28', 'b': '0.296'}]
    |       └─--[TaskA-{'a': '0.28'}]
    └─--[TaskE-{'c': '0.364', 'e': '0.486'}]
        |---[TaskF-{'c': '0.364'}]
        └─--[TaskG-{'c': '0.364'}]
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, it discards some of the w/spaces and breaks the nice tree:

[image]

Comment: try font-family:monospace;

Comment: instead of using a span with style, try a `<pre>` tag for `preformatted` text ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a span to look like a pre with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219219/how-to-change-a-span-to-look-like-a-pre-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [monospace font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), so no matter the character, the size it takes is the same for each characters

```html
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;font-family:monospace;">
└─--[TaskD-{'a': '0.28', 'b': '0.296', 'c': '0.364', 'e': '0.486'}]
    |---[TaskC-{'a': '0.28', 'b': '0.296', 'c': '0.364'}]
    |   └─--[TaskB-{'a': '0.28', 'b': '0.296'}]
    |       └─--[TaskA-{'a': '0.28'}]
    └─--[TaskE-{'c': '0.364', 'e': '0.486'}]
        |---[TaskF-{'c': '0.364'}]
        └─--[TaskG-{'c': '0.364'}]
</span>
```

Searching on the web, you'll find lots of monospace fonts, Choose the ones that fits your design best.

Comment: Thank you G-Cyrillus. I used `Courier New`.